# Не удаётся установить NgRx в проект Angular. В чём может быть дело?

Tags: angular, npm, ngrx

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я установил NgRx так как показано на сайте.
В итоге получаю ошибку.
Удалил, почистил node_modules, опять инсталлировал. Всё точно так же.
В чём может быть дело?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

У меня такая же проблема возникла, так понимаю, связано с версиями Angular:

в 12 работает, в 11 надо использовать [другую версию NGRX](https://ngrx.io/guide/migration/v11).

У меня получилось убрать ошибку после изменения строки в package.json:

"@ngrx/store": "^11.0.0"